# Office 2013 installation fails trying to modify Microsoft Uighur Bold (MSUIGHUB.TTF) font

Tags: windows-7, installation, fonts, microsoft-office-2013, dreamspark

I am trying to install a DreamSpark (education) copy of Microsoft Office 2013. While installing, the following error occurs:

> Error 1321. Setup cannot modify the file
>   C:\Windows\Fonts\MSUIGHUB.TTF. Verify that the file exists in your
>   system and that you have sufficient permissions to modify it.

It all started after downgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 7, both x64. Afterwards I got an error of being unable to activate my (already activated) Office 2013 (although it was functional), so I uninstalled and now trying to reinstall again.

I tried downloading the file from the internet and posting it there, still have the same issue.